# CONVERT clause in CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This query:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT (a.clientid) AS NumChild
   ,sub.eligtype 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN eligibilitytyperecalc IN ('1', '4', '5', '7') THEN 'EstCondition' 
            WHEN eligibilitytyperecalc IN ('2', '6') THEN 'EstDelay' 
            WHEN eligibilitytyperecalc IN ('3', '8') THEN 'AtRisk' 
            ELSE 'Missing' 
        END AS EligType 
    FROM       
        ei_archive..closed_fy13_clientstatus13) AS sub 
INNER JOIN 
   ei_archive..closed_fy13_clientstatus13 a ON sub.eligtype = a.eligibilitytyperecalc
WHERE      
   fy13_finalclientstatus = 14
   AND programid <>40
   AND programid = 01
GROUP BY   
   sub.eligtype
```

Returns the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AtRisk' to data type smallint.

I understand the problem (different data types) but cannot determine where to put the CONVERT clause. I have tried it in the first select statement, in the CASE statement , and the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to convert the value `'AtRisk'` to a numeric value which is not possible.  You could include the numeric field in your subquery and join on that:

```
SELECT COUNT (a.clientid) AS NumChild
    , sub.eligtype 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        eligibilitytyperecalc ,   // include key value
        CASE 
            WHEN eligibilitytyperecalc IN ('1', '4', '5', '7') THEN 'EstCondition' 
            WHEN eligibilitytyperecalc IN ('2', '6') THEN 'EstDelay' 
            WHEN eligibilitytyperecalc IN ('3', '8') THEN 'AtRisk' 
            ELSE 'Missing' 
        END AS EligType 
    FROM ei_archive..closed_fy13_clientstatus13) AS sub 
INNER JOIN ei_archive..closed_fy13_clientstatus13 a 
    ON sub.eligibilitytyperecalc = a.eligibilitytyperecalc // join on key field
WHERE  fy13_finalclientstatus = 14
    AND programid <>40
    AND programid = 01
GROUP  BY sub.eligtype
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe field eligibilitytyperecalc of table ei_archive..closed_fy13_clientstatus13 is a integer, so convert your a.eligibilitytyperecalc to a char/varchar because you are comparing it with string (ON sub.eligtype = a.eligibilitytyperecalc). Try the below code

```
SELECT 
COUNT (a.clientid) AS NumChild
,sub.eligtype 
FROM 
(SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN eligibilitytyperecalc IN ('1', '4', '5', '7') THEN 'EstCondition' 
        WHEN eligibilitytyperecalc IN ('2', '6') THEN 'EstDelay' 
        WHEN eligibilitytyperecalc IN ('3', '8') THEN 'AtRisk' 
        ELSE 'Missing' 
    END AS EligType 
FROM       
    ei_archive..closed_fy13_clientstatus13) AS sub 
INNER JOIN 
ei_archive..closed_fy13_clientstatus13 a ON sub.eligtype = cast(a.eligibilitytyperecalc        as char(10))
WHERE      
 fy13_finalclientstatus = 14
AND programid <>40
AND programid = 01
GROUP BY   
sub.eligtype
```

Comment: It is an integer; however, when I ran the code it returned the column names but no counts.